# How can I remove a specific string from another string in Fortran?

Tags: string, fortran

In Fortran, how can I remove a specific string from another string? For example:
string1='c/test/run1/runfile.dat',
string2='runfile.dat'.
I want to remove string2 ('runfile.dat') from string1('c/test/run1/runfile.dat') and get the result as 'c/test/run1/'
How can I do that. I am using Fortran f90, with visual studio.

Comment: Does the substring always appear at the end of the string? Does it appear exactly once in the string?

Comment: Do you mind if the result string has trailing blanks or not?

Comment: The `index` intrinsic function will probably be of use

Comment: The substring always appear at the end of the string

Comment: the resulting string should not have a trailing blank.

Comment: Please read about the [`index` intrinsic function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37011118/3157076), and try to use it. If you struggle, please update with question with your attempt

Comment: You might want to look at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/INDEX-intrinsic.html as well which includes the Fortran90 and later interface for the `index` intrinsic, which has extra arguments that may be useful compared to that in the deleted Fortran77 standard

Comment: I could solve it by using index, trim, adjustl functions in Fortran

Answer (score 1):

May be this is too obvious, or I haven't understood your problem properly, but if you know that substring `string2` has `m` characters (`len_trim()`) and really appears at the end of `string1` that has `n` characters, you can just use the first `n-m` characters of `string1`

```
string1(1:n-m)
```

or in full

```
string1(1:len_trim(string1)-len_trim(string2))
```

You can verify that `string2` really appears in `string1` and find the position, using `index()` as stated in the comments, but if you know it is there, just take the substring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a library to do it then please have a look at the [StringiFor](https://github.com/szaghi/StringiFor).

In particular, see the following example.

- [Getting base directory](https://github.com/szaghi/StringiFor#complex-scenario)

Solution 2

You can use the following code which I have returned for you.

[find_replace_string](https://gist.github.com/vickysharma0812/0b7f3c9702d904d415a208901b6122fc)

```
PROGRAM main
USE iso_fortran_env, ONLY: dfp => real64, i4b => int32, stdout => output_unit
IMPLICIT NONE
CHARACTER(len=:), ALLOCATABLE :: master
CHARACTER(len=:), ALLOCATABLE :: slave
CHARACTER(len=:), ALLOCATABLE :: ans
INTEGER(i4b) :: indx_start, slave_len, indx_end, master_len
  !! main
master = 'c/test/run1/runfile.dat'
master_len = LEN_TRIM(master)
slave = 'runfile.dat'
slave_len = LEN_TRIM(slave)
indx_start = INDEX(master, slave)
IF (indx_start .EQ. 0) THEN
  WRITE (stdout, "(a)") TRIM(slave)//" not found in "//TRIM(master)
  ans = TRIM(master)
ELSE
  WRITE (stdout, "(a)") TRIM(slave)//" found in "//TRIM(master)
  ans = master//master(1:indx_start - 1)//master(indx_start + slave_len:master_len)
END IF

WRITE(stdout, "(a)") "ans : " // TRIM(ans)

END PROGRAM main
```

Regards
Vikas